# How to invalidate the template once set?

Tags: php, phalcon

### Question

Please tell me how to invalidate the template once set with the setTemplateAfter method on Phalcon 3 so as not to refer to the template.

---

### Overview

The current configuration is extended by IndexController ControllerBase.

In the initialize method of ControllerBase, set the template with setTemplateAfter as follows.

```
$this->view->setTemplateAfter('common');
```

In the expanded IndexController, since the template is unnecessary, an error occurs although the following is executed.

```
$this->view->setTemplateAfter('');
```

*I am thinking that I do not want to change to ControllerBase as much as possible because the template is used by another controller.

---

### Error message

```
View 'layouts/' was not found in any of the views directory
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View->_engineRender(Array, 'layouts/', false, true, NULL)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View->render('index', 'index')
#2 /mnt/raid/serverapps/www/lashca/public/index.php(42): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#3 {main}
```

---

### Source code

controllers/ControllerBase.php

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
class ControllerBase extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->view->setTemplateAfter('common');
    }
}
```

controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->setTemplateAfter('');
    }
}
```

---

### Environment

- CentOS 7.4(x64)
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 7.0.26
- Phalcon Framework 3.2.4
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.38

Comment: Do you completely want to remove the view layout? Then you can do `$this->view->disable()`

Comment: I do not want to use layout, but I want to use view.
`$this->view->disable()` certainly makes layout ineffective but view is also invalid, so I would like to know another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable certain levels of view rendering via `$this->view->disable()`.

For example, if you want to disable the "template after"-rendering you can do this:

```
$this->view->disableLevel([
    View::LEVEL_AFTER_TEMPLATE  => true
]);
```

Check the [documentation](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.3/reference/views.html#control-rendering-levels) if you want to disable other levels of the view.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It was solved by setting the following.
`$this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_LAYOUT);`